# How can I detect when any youtube video is played using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to fire off a quick tracking script when any youtube video is played.  Is this possible with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Are you using an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192346/is-there-any-way-to-detect-with-javascript-when-a-youtube-video-starts-playing

Comment: @Rennie Yes, I'm using iframes.

Comment: @jasonlam604 Thanks, but I'm looking to track any youtube video played, not individual videos.

Comment: If the answer from @jasonlam604 is not what you're looking for and only want to fire something when a user plays (or clicks) the video, maybe you can map the Iframe. placing a transparent div over the iframe with position absolute.